# What methods and objects does React package contain?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and wondering what react package contains, that is, we can import React and {Component} from 'react' as far as I know. Where is it possible to find, at least, the list of functions or objects that react package provides? Also, does react package contain component lifecycle methods? I really hope for your kind help

Comment: Check the API Reference on the official React website https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html

Comment: @Khauri, thank you for your kind comments, as I can see component lifecycle methods are not in react package. The question what makes react recognize or look for lifecycle methods if react package does not contain those methods? Thank you:)

Comment: Lifecycle methods are here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle Also typically typing things like "react api" or "react lifecycle methods" into google will get you a lot of useful information. React knows what methods to expect your class to have and will simply call your methods when it needs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the api reference for react: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html

And detailed component reference(You can find lifecycle methods here) https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: Yes that's correct if you are using class components. There are also functional components. They don't have any lifecycle methods - Because they are functions :) -. In that case you can manipulate state using hooks (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). Finally, I strongly suggest following tutorial on official website it really helps if you are new.